# Error is SQL syntax, unable to update mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

While updating a column 'client_name' in client table i got following error;

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE client-id=2' at line 1**

Here's the code:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE client SET client_name=%s, WHERE client-id=%s",
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));
        mysql_select_db($database_trackntrace, $trackntrace);
        $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $trackntrace) or die(mysql_error()); }
```

I am unable to rectify the error, need a little help.

Thanks

Comment: `client-id` or `client_id`?

Comment: Remove `,` before `WHERE`

Comment: what is the datatype of 'client_name' and 'client-id'

Comment: Yes, you have error in the syntax. This is not the place, where we shoiuld find syntax errors, since the official doc provides the syntax flow. `UPDATE table SET col = %s WHERE col2 = %s`, you have an unnecessary comma after the `col` and before `WHERE`

Comment: why is there a comma before where?

Comment: @MarkBaker its client-id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an additional `,` comma remove this

```
UPDATE client SET client_name=%s, WHERE client-id=%s
```

to

```
UPDATE client SET client_name=%s WHERE client-id=%s
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma that doesn't belong in your query.

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE client SET client_name=%s, WHERE client-id=%s"
//----------------------------------------------------^ That one
```

Remove it and that should fix it.